# Python 3.5.1 Vs 3.5.2 - String to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, floating-point

I am using the following code to convert the string into a float.,

```
number = "2.05"
float_val = float(number)
print(float_val)
```

When I run this code with Python 3.5.2, the output is as shown below
[image]

I am running the same code on a different machine with Python 3.5.1, the output is as follows
[image]

My expected output is as in Python 3.5.2. What should be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get the first output in 3.6.3. The difference is probably more due to the machine or OS, not the Python version. Maybe one is 32-bit the other is 64-bit?

Comment: @Barmar Machine with 3.5.2 is x64 and the one with 3.5.1 is arm

Comment: So, yeah, different architectures, slight differences in float handling…